# QRegExp not finding expected string pattern

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I am working in Qt 5.2, and I have a piece of code that takes in a string and enters one of several if statements based on its format. One of the formats searched for is the letters "RCV", followed by a variable amount of numbers, a decimal, and then one more number. There can be more than one of these values in the line, separated by "|", for example it could one value like "RCV0123456.1" or mulitple values like "RCV12345.1|RCV678.9". Right now I am using QRegExp class to find this, like this:

```
QString value = "RCV000030249.2|RCV000035360.2";    //Note: real test value from my code
if(QRegExp("^[RCV\d+\.\d\|?]+$").exactMatch(value))
    std::cout << ":D" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << ":(" << std::endl;
```

I want it to use the if statement, but it keeps going into the else statement. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the regular expression?

Comment: I think you have to escape the back slashes in the regular expression string like `"^[RCV\\d+\\.\\d\\|?]+$"`. Strange that it is even compiles.

Comment: @vahancho Thanks for the tip, I didn't need to make the change exactly like that but it got me on the right track. I needed just one backslash before '.' and '|' because I want it to recognize the character itself instead of a metacharacter they usually represent, but since I was looking for '\d' I needed '\\d' so it wouldn't just match the letter 'd'. As for the compiling comment, I think it does make sense that it compiles since syntax is still valid, it just looks for the wrong thing. Again, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @vahancho: It compiles with warnings (g++).

Comment: @Unihedron thanks for your comment, the [] actually does work though, it was a different problem, vahancho's comment and my response cover the solution

Comment: Escape the backslashes will find you the first occurence. If you just need to check if at least one is found your fine, for finding all occurences you will have to loop through the string by having a offset of the last match.

Comment: You will have to double quote the \\. too, otherwise you will match any character here, for example: RCV00a0. The doulbe quotes are required for C++ String escaping. Since you want to match '.' the correct match would be ``\.``, which translates to ``\\.`` in c++ string.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression should be like @vahancho mentionet in a comment:

```
if(QRegExp("^[RCV\\d+\\.\\d\\|?]+$").exactMatch(value))
```

If you use C++11, then you can use its raw strings feature:

```
if(QRegExp(R"(^[RCV\d+\.\d\|?]+$)").exactMatch(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Aside from escaping the backslashes which others has mentioned in answers and comments,*

> There can be more than one of these values in the line, separated by "|", for example it could one value like "RCV0123456.1" or mulitple values like "RCV12345.1|RCV678.9".

`[RCV\d+\.\d\|?]` may not be doing what you expect. Perhaps you want `()` instead of `[]`:

```
/^
  [RCV\d+\.\d\|?]+ # More than one of characters from the list:
                   # R, C, V, a digit, a +, a dot, a digit, a |, a ?
 $/x
```

```
/^
  (
    RCV\d+\.\d     # RCV, some digits, a dot, followed by a digit
    \|?            # Optional: a |
  )+               # Quantifier of one or more
 $/x
```

Also, maybe you could revise the regex such that the optional `|` requires the group to be matched *again*:

```
/^
  (RCV\d+\.\d)     # RCV, some digits, a dot, followed by a digit
  (
    \|(?1)         # A |, then match subpattern 1 (Above)
  )+               # Quantifier of one or more
 $/x
```

Comment: Not sure about ``\|(?1)`` but wouldn't match the subpattern be ``\|($1)``? Won't help the op though, QRegExp does not use capturedGroups in regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if only valid occurences in line with the addition to require an `|` starting second occurence (having your implementation would not require the `|` even with double quotes):

```
QString value = "RCV000030249.2|RCV000035360.2";    //Note: real test value from my code
if(QRegExp("^RCV\\d+\\.\\d(\\|RCV\\d+\\.\\d)*$").exactMatch(value))
    std::cout << ":D" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << ":(" << std::endl;
```